# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods not called when UITableView is a subview of UIView (data initially loads)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UIView` that contains a `UITableView`.  These are managed by a `UIViewController` that inherits the delegate methods `UITableViewDelegate` and `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`.  I am able to populate the table just fine using the `NSFetchedResultsController`, however the delegate methods (specifically `controllerWillChangeContent`) are not called when changes are made to managed objects in the `fetchObjects`.

I have checked independently that changes are made to the objects, and those changes I have reflected in the cells, however you must manually reload the cells (scrolling up) to see the changes occur.  The behavior I am looking for is that when the changes are made to the object (via save), that the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods fire so I can make the updates to the table view.

Just to be clear, the data is populated from the database when the view loads, so I know the code pulls that just fine.

**Header interface**

```
@interface HSAwardsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

**init method - Setting up managedObjectContext (uses Magical Record)**

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        HSInternalDB *dbInstance = [HSInternalDB getInternalDB];
        self.persistentStoreCoordinator = [dbInstance getPersistentStoreCoordinator];
        self.managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];

        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;

        NSError *error;
        if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
            // Update to handle the error appropriately.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            exit(-1);  // Fail
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Setting up the NSFetchedResultsController and assigning the delegate**

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Award"];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"gameTypeIdentifier" ascending:NO];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [theFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    theFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;

    // Listen for this notification so that the managedObjectContext runs on the main thread
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextChanged:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}



- (void)contextChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [notification object];
    if ([context isEqual:self.managedObjectContext]) {
        return;
    }

    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(contextChanged:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }

    [[self managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

As far as I can see, all the connections are are made in code or in the storyboard.  I know a change is recorded in my database because I am listening for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.

This has me stumped, so I appreciate any suggestions or bread crumbs.  I'm happy to answer any questions or post more code if needed!

Comment: Were you able to sort this out? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

contextChanged: should be called on MainThread since it involve UI update.

Comment: Yes, I believe that I am doing ensuring this is the case with `if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(contextChanged:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }`

Comment: Is your managedObjectContext changed on main thread? If not, it will not trigger the frc delegate.

Comment: @John don't you know how to trigger delegate methods if context changed in background thread? I mean i create new context with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType, set parent context and perform block where i add objects to CoreData.